# correlation of a vector across all column in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, across

I have a data frame in R (taken from the dplyr's site [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)):

```
library(dplyr)
gdf <-
  tibble(g = c(1, 1, 2, 3), v1 = 10:13, v2 = 20:23) %>%
  group_by(g)
gdf
```

Resulting to:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   g [3]
      g    v1    v2
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1    10    20
2     1    11    21
3     2    12    22
4     3    13    23
```

Now I have a vector :

```
y <- rnorm(4);y
```

I want to measure the correlation of y with v1 and the correlation of y with v2 simultaneously.

The `across()` function might do the job

```
gdf %>% mutate(across(v1:v2, ~ cor(.x,y)))
```

but R reports me an error :

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(v1:v2, ~cor(.x, y))`.
x incompatible dimensions
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: g = 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Your data frame is grouped so you're trying to assess correlation of vectors of varying length (1 and 2) with `y` which is length 4. Just ungroup and it works, although probably cleanest to use `summarize()` since `cor()` returns a single value.

Comment: @caldwellst can you provide some code as an answer? your idea is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `cor()` requires same dimension for both `x` and `y`, you cannot group rows together, otherwise, they will not have 4 elements to match with 4 values in `y`.

### Prepare data and library

```
library(dplyr)

gdf <-
  tibble(g = c(1, 1, 2, 3), v1 = 10:13, v2 = 20:23)

y <- rnorm(4)
[1] 0.59390132 0.91897737 0.78213630 0.07456498
```

### mutate()

If you want to keep `v1` and `v2` in the output, use the `.names` argument to indicate the names of the new columns. `{.col}` refers to the column name that `across` is acting on.

```
gdf %>% mutate(across(v1:v2, ~ cor(.x,y), .names = "{.col}_cor"))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
      g    v1    v2 v1_cor v2_cor
  <dbl> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    10    20 -0.591 -0.591
2     1    11    21 -0.591 -0.591
3     2    12    22 -0.591 -0.591
4     3    13    23 -0.591 -0.591
```

### summarise()

If you only want the `cor()` output in the results, you can use `summarise`

```
gdf %>% summarize(across(v1:v2, ~ cor(.x,y)))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      v1     v2
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 -0.591 -0.591
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```r
cor(gdf[,-1], y)

#>         [,1]
#> v1 0.5080586
#> v2 0.5080586
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

gdf <-
  tibble(g = c(1, 1, 2, 3), v1 = 10:13, v2 = 20:23)

set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(4)

map_dfc(gdf[,-1], ~ cor(.x, y))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      v1    v2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.508 0.508
```